# Running Scrapy crawler from a main function

Tags: python, scrapy

Ihave wriiten a crawler in scrapy but I would want to initiate the crwaling by using main method

```
import sys, getopt
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.http    import Request
import re

class TutsplusItem(scrapy.Item):
  title = scrapy.Field()



class MySpider(Spider):
  name = "tutsplus"
  allowed_domains   = ["bbc.com"]
  start_urls = ["http://www.bbc.com/"]

  def __init__(self, *args):
      try:
          opts, args = getopt.getopt(args, "hi:o:", ["ifile=", "ofile="])
      except getopt.GetoptError:
          print 'test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
          sys.exit(2)

      super(MySpider, self).__init__(self,*args)



  def parse(self, response):
    links = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()


    # We stored already crawled links in this list
    crawledLinks = []

    # Pattern to check proper link
    # I only want to get the tutorial posts
   # linkPattern = re.compile("^\/tutorials\?page=\d+")


    for link in links:
      # If it is a proper link and is not checked yet, yield it to the Spider
      #if linkPattern.match(link) and not link in crawledLinks:
      if not link in crawledLinks:
        link = "http://www.bbc.com" + link
        crawledLinks.append(link)
        yield Request(link, self.parse)

    titles = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "media__link")]/text()').extract()
    count=0
    for title in titles:
      item = TutsplusItem()
      item["title"] = title
      print("Title is : %s" %title)
      yield item
```

Instead of using scrapy runspider Crawler.py arg1 arg2
 I would like to have a seprate class with main function and initiate scrapy from there. How to this?

Answer (score -1):

There are different ways to approach this, but I suggest the following:

Have a main.py file on the same directory that will open a new process and launch the spider with the parameters you need.

The main.py file would have something like the following:

```
import subprocess
scrapy_command = 'scrapy runspider {spider_name} -a param_1="{param_1}"'.format(spider_name='your_spider', param_1='your_value')

process = subprocess.Popen(scrapy_command, shell=True)
```

With this code, you just need to call your main file.

```
python main.py
```

Hope it helps.